# WRAP_CONTENT not working in TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am trying to create a 4 column display using TableLayout. I have set up the views in the columns to WRAP_CONTENT for layout width. I then put in some test values to see the results. Instead of shrink down to the width of the device screen it expands beyond the borders of the device. Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:text="Player" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:text="Player" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:text="Player" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:text="Player" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:text="26" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:text="26" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText7"
            android:text="26" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText8"
            android:text="26" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

This is what I am getting. Only about 1 and a half of the 4 columns are showing.
[image]

This is what I am expecting. The only way I can get this is to put specific dp values in the layout width.
[image]

I just want the 4 columns to fill to the available width of the screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of `android:ems="10"` in xml `TextView` attribute.

try with `android:ems="5"` or less

**OR**

You can achieve same by using

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
```

to all `TextView`s. And adding `android:orientation="horizontal"` to `TableRow`

Hope it'll help.

Comment: The lower ems did the trick. Thanks. I'll have to try the other one too to see the difference.

Comment: layout_weight gave me better results. Thanks